# Cache-friendly sqare matrix transposition logic issue

Tags: c, algorithm, matrix, caching, transpose

This code is a transposition algorithm specifically optimized to work on square matrices with rows and columns that are multiples of 8. The optimization involves processing components later that satisfy certain conditions, which are commented out in the code. However, the transpose fails in the wrong place.

```c
void block8x4_opt(int M, int N, int A[N][M], int B[M][N])
{
    register int i, j, i1, j1;
    for (i = 0; i < N; i += 8)
        for (j = 0; j < M; j += 4) {
            if (j == i || j == i + 4) { /* same block */
                for (i1 = i; i1 < i + 8 ; i1++)
                    for (j1 = j; j1 < j + 4 ; j1++) {
                        if (i1 == j1 || i1 == j1 + 4) /* same row */
                            continue;
                        B[j1][i1] = A[i1][j1];
                    }
                for (j1 = j; j1 < j + 4; j1++) {
                    B[j1][j1] = A[j1][j1]; /* i1 == j1 */
                    B[j1][j1+4] = A[j1+4][j1]; /* i1 == j1 + 4 */
                }
                continue;   
            }
            for (i1 = i; i1 < i + 8 ; i1++)
                for (j1 = j; j1 < j + 4 ; j1++)
                    B[j1][i1] = A[i1][j1];
        }
}
```

Below is the result of transposing 8x8 matrix A to B using the code above.

the problem occurs at (0,5),(1,6),(2,7).

The weird thing is, the part I skipped with the above algorithm is the top of that part, the line 4-13-22-31. It's the line just below it that causes the problem, and the other blocks don't cause any problems.

```
*************** matrix A *****************
         0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7
        ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...
  0:     0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7
  1:     8    9   10   11   12   13   14   15
  2:    16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23
  3:    24   25   26   27   28   29   30   31
  4:    32   33   34   35   36   37   38   39
  5:    40   41   42   43   44   45   46   47
  6:    48   49   50   51   52   53   54   55
  7:    56   57   58   59   60   61   62   63

              **** matrix B ****
         0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7
        ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...
  0:     0    8   16   24   32   40   48   56
  1:     1    9   17   25   33   41   49   57
  2:     2   10   18   26   34   42   50   58
  3:     3   11   19   27   35   43   51   59
  4:     4   12   20   28   36   44   52   60
  5:     ?   13   21   29   37   45   53   61
  6:     6    0   22   30   38   46   54   62
  7:     7   15    ?   31   39   47   55   63
```

I would really appreciate it if you could find the problem with my code.

Comment: First off, you see that whenever the difference between column and row indices are ```5``` you have an issue. So, you *HAVE TO* ```debug``` your code and look carefully for those indices that make difference ```5```. I guess in ```B[j1][j1+4] = A[j1+4][j1];``` line you must debug very carefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your algorithm is wrong.

Look at this:

```
for (i = 0; i < N; i += 8)
    for (j = 0; j < M; j += 4) {
        if (j == i || j == i + 4) { /* same block */
```

For 8x8 matrix both `N`and `M` is 8 so it's like:

```
for (i = 0; i < 8; i += 8)
    for (j = 0; j < 8; j += 4) {
        if (j == i || j == i + 4) { /* same block */
```

So which values will `i` and `j`take:

```
i==0, j==0
i==0, j==4
// Now the inner loop ends as j becomes 8 due j+=4
// Now the outer loop ends as i becomes 8 due i+=8
```

So the `if` statement will only be executed for (i,j) as (0,0) and (0,4). If both cases the `if` condition will be true. As the last statement in the body of the `if` is a `continue`, the code will never reach:

```
        for (i1 = i; i1 < i + 8 ; i1++)
            for (j1 = j; j1 < j + 4 ; j1++)
                B[j1][i1] = A[i1][j1];
```

Another issue... When `j` is 4 consider this:

```
            for (j1 = j; j1 < j + 4; j1++) {
                B[j1][j1] = A[j1][j1]; /* i1 == j1 */
                B[j1][j1+4] = A[j1+4][j1]; /* i1 == j1 + 4 */
            }
```

So `j1` will take the value 4, 5, 6, 7 and you have

```
                B[j1][j1+4] = A[j1+4][j1]; /* i1 == j1 + 4 */
                      ^^^^
                      ups... out of bound, i.e. 8, 9, 10, 11
```

A simple advice. Add some `printf` whenever you write to `b`. Like:

```
B[j1][j1+4] = A[j1+4][j1];
printf("Line %d: B[%d][%d] = A[%d][%d]\n", __LINE__, j1, j1+4, j1+4, j1)";
```

Then it's easy to check all assignments to `B` for correctness.